# Which is faster: dropping all tables in an sqlite file or deleting the file itself?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have an sqlite database where every once in a while I need to wipe it completely and recreate tables with their relations. Is it faster if I drop all tables and rebuild them, or delete the entire file using `System.IO.File.Delete()` and recreate it?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: _"every once in a while I need to wipe it completely and recreate tables with their relations"_ it hardly seems worth worrying about it, as pointed out in the link above, and I wouldn't really expect much difference anyway. But if you really want to know, try it both ways yourself and measure it.

Comment: As an addition to @stuartd: and don't forget to post your results ;-)

Comment: give a command of drop a table name then all the tables will be removed

Comment: For sure deleting the file will be much faster. Because it is not needing any parsing for sql statements or executing logic.

Comment: Faster doesn't matter, although deleting the file is *always* faster than deleting rows inside transactions and updating transaction logs. Do you want to roll back if something goes wrong? Do you have permissions in the file system to create new files? If not, you can't use `File.Delete()`. If you really don't care, just call `File.Delete()`.